# Update values from one row to a new row based on another column's value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to accomplish this. Here's my table:

```
Person_ID | Attribute_ID | Datetime
1000        99             1965-01-01 00:00:00.000
1000        19             NULL
2000        99             2002-05-02 00:00:00.000
2000        19             NULL
```

I need to find all Person IDs where an Attribute_ID of 99 is not null. Then I need to copy that DateTime value to the Datetime associated with the attribute_ID of 19. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are rows unique on `Person_ID` & `Attribute_ID` i.e. there will only ever be a single row with the same `Person_ID` & `Attribute_ID`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. For example, there will never be multiple rows where Person_ID = 1000 & Attribute_ID = 1. Person_ID and Attribute_ID together make the primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Person_ID & Attribute_ID is unique then the following should work (untested though):

```
update T
  set [DateTime] = X.[DateTime]
from MyTable T
inner join (
  select Person_ID, [DateTime]
  from MyTable
  where Attribute_ID = 99 and [DateTime] is not null
) X on X.Person_ID = T.Person_ID
where Attribute_ID = 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the not null DateTime that belongs in the row with the same Person_ID:

```
update tablename t
  set DateTime = 
(select DateTime from tablename
where Attribute_ID = 99 and Person_ID = t.Person_ID and DateTime is not null) 
WHERE Attribute_ID = 19
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  UPDATE TABLE SET DATETIME = (SELECT DISTINCT 
   DATETIME FROM TABLE WHERE DATETIME IS NOT 
   NULL AND ATTRIBUTE_ID =99 AND PERSON_ID=TABLE.PERSON_ID) WHERE 
     ATTRIBUTE_ID=19;
```

This query retrieves the distinct datetime values for attribute_id as 99 except nulls and updates those datetime values for attribute_id as 19 thereafter.